# The Fibonacci-like recurrence $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+m$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any formula for the following integer sequence defined by the recurrence relation $F_n =F_{n-1} + F_{n-2} + m$ , where $m \in \Bbb N$?

I'ts seems to be similar to Fibonacci sequence but its sequence is extended.

What is the sum of it's N-terms ?

Comment: That remains a linear recurrence relation. It is easy to solve using e.g. characteristic matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $G_n=F_n+m$. Then $$G_n-m=F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+m=G_{n-1}+G_{n-2}-2m+m\\ G_n=G_{n-1}+G_{n-2}$$

Comment: It is fibonacci sequence for example 1,1,2,3,5,8,....